# Facebook API Request failed with error

Tags: facebook, url, server

I'm creating app using facebookAPI login system. I wanna make my app in public. When I added app Privacy Policy URL(http://b446c081.ngrok.io), raised this error.

"
You must submit a valid Privacy Policy URL in order to be compliant with Facebook Platform. Request failed with error: Could Not Connect To Server: Check that the webserver is running, and that there are no firewalls blocking Facebook's crawlers.
"

Of course my server is running, I can't understand "Check that there are no firewalls blocking Facebook's crawlers"

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=i69w0n&s=9#.Wsg4MGaB1p8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug on the Facebook side of things that doesn't allow Ngrok port-forwards as Policy URLs. I would recommend pushing your data to a service such as Heroku (which has a free tier, no card details needed) and a free URL that Facebook will accept as a Policy URL.

Comment: Thanks, I deployed myapp using Heroku and got this url: https://restaurant111.herokuapp.com.
Then I added it in privacy policy url, so I got this error...

Comment: You must submit a valid Privacy Policy URL in order to be compliant with Facebook Platform. Request failed with error: Bad Response Code: URL returned a bad HTTP response code.

Comment: Solved. It was heroku's hosting problem. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help, hope you don't have any more issues!